# How do I enable auto select pose mode when clicking on an armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode

When I click on an armature I wanna be able to enter from object mode to pose mode immediately rather than having to select it manually first. I've seen some downloaded rigs that have enabled this feature but I don't know how they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable Edit ⇾ Lock Object Modes

[image]

Then you will be able to select objects while keeping armature in Pose Mode.